# How to run shell script in two sqlplus instances

Tags: shell, sh, sqlplus

Is there a way to run a shell script that when it updates one sqlplus instance it will update a second?

Code:

```
echo "Please enter last name: 'input;"
    read input
    Statement2="INSERT INTO users VALUES ('"$input"');"
    output1=$($sqlplus -s User/Pass@connection <<EOF
    set head off
    select count (*) from users
    where fname = '$input';
    EXIT;
    EOF
    )

    read -p "User $input appears $output1 times. Create user? [Y/n]" answer
    if [ -z "$answer" -o "$answer" == "y" -o "$answer" == "Y" ]
    then

    $sqlplus -s User/Pass@connection << Eossql
    set autocommit on
    set head off
    $Statement2
        quit;
    Eossql

    else
        echo "Not creating user"
    fi
```

How can I update a second sqlpus instance with a separate userid and password if the end user selects (y)

Thanks!

Comment: I think this question is unclear. Perhaps rewrite the question

Comment: @EdHeal If the user selects "y" in the above code it will run "statement2" which is an insert into the table in instance 1. I was asking if the user selects "y" it will run "statement 2" it two separate instances with separate user ID's and Passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the SQL code to run on two instances in a variable, and then reuse it:

```
sql=$(cat << EOF
set autocommit on
set head off
$Statement2
    quit;
EOF
)
$sqlplus -s User/Pass@connection <<< "$sql"
$sqlplus -s User2/Pass2@connection2 <<< "$sql"
```